# How do I store JWT in Next.js application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jwt

Lets assume I generate JWT for a user, that has logged into my page. I would store it in redux, to make it accessible. In plain react + react router, if the user were to change to another page, it would not refresh the redux store and I would still be able to retrieve the JWT from the redux on different page. But Next.js refreshes after the route changes. So how to properly handle the JWT in Next.js, without saving it into local storage / session storage which are obviously not safe?

Comment: save it inside cookies?

Comment: What I do with JWT in next is store in them in cookies on login and use context API with useEffect to bring them to the front end even on page refresh

Comment: I thought that the main idea of JWT is that it doesnt need to be stored. Thats why I asked this question. So I will store it as a http-only cookie.

Comment: _"But Next.js refreshes after the route changes"_ - not necessarily. If you're using Next.js built-in router for navigations the pages won't fully reload and state can be kept client-side.